# What does the Gedit Plugin called "Quick open" do and/or provide?

Tags: gedit, plugins

What does the "Quick open" plugin do? It says that it "Quick open: Quickly open files.", but I can't see what's changed after I enable it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'Quick open' plugin adds a 'quick open' menu in the Gedit window under File.
It's used to quickly open files you have recently used.
Keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

See screenshot below.

[image]

When you click on it, you get this window with your recent files.
You can also search for the file you want.
Double click on the file you want to open it in a new tab.

[image]